# Angular chaining requests in resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase, angularfire

I have a page displaying a user and locations that user is active in. Per the Firebase documentation on flat structure, I am storing the user and the location in two different nods. I want ui-router to resolve the user and an array of the locations before it loads the page.

Below is the code I am using but I can't figure out how to write the return statement for the location variable so that it will wait for all the locations to be retrieved. (As far as I can see there is no option in angularfire to retrieve all of the locations with one call thought that solution would be very welcome.)

```
resolve: {
      user: function(firebase, $firebaseObject, $stateParams){
        var user = $firebaseObject(firebase.user.child($stateParams.id));
        return user.$loaded().then(function(){
          return user;
        })
      },
      locations: function(firebase, $firebaseObject, user) {
        var locations = [];
        angular.forEach(user.locations, function (value, location) {
          var retrievedLocation = $firebaseObject(firebase.location.child(location));
          retrievedLocation.$loaded().then(function(){
            locations.push(retrievedLocation);
          })
        })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to roll your own promise with $q:

```
function ($q, firebase, $firebaseObject, user) {
    var promiseArray = [];
    angular.forEach(user.locations, function (value, location) {
        var retrievedLocation = $firebaseObject(firebase.location.child(location));
        promiseArray.push(retrievedLocation.$loaded().then(function(){
            return retrievedLocation;
        });
    })

    return $q.all(promiseArray).then(function(data){
        var locations = data;
        return locations;
    });
}
```

**note** clearly you don't need the locations variable or the .then at all any more. You return could just be:

```
return $q.all(promiseArray)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried but it's not working for some reason. It resolves in the resolve block but is undefined in the controller. $q.all(console.log()) returns several locations

Comment: This should work... in your controller you should be injecting locations. $q.all(console.log()) doesn't really make sense, not sure I understand that.

Comment: This is so embarrassing. I had a bracket in the wrong place. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Happens to the best of us.